# placing value between specific numbers in cycle

Tags: r, cycle

so lets say I have

```
x = 1,4,2
i = 2
j = 4 
k = 3
```

So i = 2 and j = 4, the point is i need to place k (3) between the numbers i,j in x so the result would be x = 1,4,3,2. I need it to work in a cycle because the numbers in i,j,k always change and so does the length of x when a new number from k is placed in x. The new x after step one is
x = 1,4,3,2 and lets say new values:

```
i = 4
j = 3
k = 5  so again in the cycle it should place 5 in x between 4 and 3 so final x = 1,4,5,3,2
```

Is there a way i could do it?

Answer (score 1):

When i is always the number before j,

You could use `append` function:

ie:

```
x = c(1,4,2)
i = 4 
k = 3 

x <- append(x, k, match(i, x))
x
[1] 1 4 3 2

 i = 4
 k = 5
x <- append(x, k, match(i, x))
x
[1] 1 4 5 3 2
```

Putting this in a function:

```
insert <- function(x, k, i){
    append(x, k, match(i, x))
}
```

Note that you did not specify what would happen if you had more than 1 four in your vector. ie `x<- c(1,4,2,4,2)` where exactly do you want to place the 3? Is it after the first four or the second four? etc

Comment: Yeah so i and j are always generated from x so in the first case when x = 1,4,2 i and j were randomly picked from x thats why i = 2 and j = 4, its the numbers from x,so the numbers in x dont repeat. Sorry if i dont explaint it very well im new in this

Comment: @Obrazdoby since the numbers in x dont repeat, the function I gave above is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function :

```
insert_after <- function(x, i, k) {
  ind <- match(i, x)
  new_inds <- sort(c(seq_along(x), ind))
  new_x <- x[new_inds]
  new_x[duplicated(new_inds)] <- k
  new_x
}
x = c(1,4,2)
x <- insert_after(x, 4, 3)
x
#[1] 1 4 3 2

x <- insert_after(x, 4, 5)
x
#[1] 1 4 5 3 2
```